# how to solve sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at end of input

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Im getting this error using postgresql with sqlalchemy:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "BNB_transfers" RENAME "bnb_transfers"
```

Code I'm using:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(statement=text(f'ALTER TABLE "{tableName}" RENAME{tokenName.lower()}_transfers"'))
```

I tried renaming an existing table.

Comment: Your syntax error is as a result of missing space between `RENAME` and your new table name, also change `RENAME` to  `RENAME TO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax is [`ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME TO new_table_name;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html). You were missing the `TO`, which isn't optional. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Oz8AslyX)

```python
with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(statement=text(f"""ALTER TABLE "{tableName}" 
                                          RENAME TO {tokenName.lower()}_transfers
                                          """))
```

The error is at the end of input because without the `TO` in that spot, it could still be a valid column renaming statement: `ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME some_column TO new_column_name;` so it's as if you started that and forgot to finish.

You're likely doing this as a fix for that exact behaviour, but to anyone overlooking it: watch out for identifier quoting inconsistencies. Double-quoting it one time and leaving without quotes another time. If the new name has uppercase characters, they'll be folded to lowercase.